# How to hide files starting with dot (.) in FTP

Tags: ubuntu, ftp, vsftpd

I am using VSFTPD to access files on my server. I have seen that there some files starting dot like .bash or something . How can i hide those files from anyone using ftp to view those

Answer (score 4):

If you would bother to open a man page for `vsftpd.conf`, you would find the following option:

> **hide_file**
>
> This option can be used to set a pattern for filenames (and directory names etc.) which should be hidden from directory listings. Despite being hidden, the files / directories etc. are fully accessible to clients who know what names to actually use. Items will be hidden if their names contain the string given by hide_file, or if they match the regular expression specified by hide_file. Note that vsftpd's regular expression matching code is a simple implementation which is a subset of full regular expression functionality. See deny_file for details of exactly what regex syntax is supported.
>
> Example: hide_file={*.mp3,.hidden,hide*,h?}
>
> Default: (none)

Comment: i have used hide_file={*.mp3}     
but my ftp is still showing the mp3 file. i restarted the computer as well but nothing works

Comment: @Master Look at the example format in the `man` excerpt `solefald` posted. `hide_file={.mp3}`, not `hide_file={*.mp3}`.

Answer (score 0):

In VSFTP `/etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf` 
 
 Add this to **show** hidden files :

```
force_dot_files=YES
```

And then restart vsftpd

```
# systemctl restart vsfptpd
```

By default hidden files not displayed in vsftp list.